# Hi, I want to know how I can use ng-click with two parameters within (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <span class="navbar-brand">Suivi Des Tables</span>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active : item == itemcourant}"><a ng-click="selectItem(item);tab={{item.tab}}" href="#{{item.nom}}">{{item.nom}}</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="tab=1" href="#">test</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is : ng-click="selectItem(item);tab={{item.tab}}"

Comment: Use a semi colon to separate inline JS `ng-click="tab=1; x=2"`

Comment: Seems like that logic should be in your controller. Just create a function in your controller that select/change selected tab variables etc. Then call that function from ng-click.

Comment: ng-click="selectItem(item);tab=item.tab" -- no need for the interpolation expression.

Comment: I already try this solution but dosn't work. ng-click="selectItem(item);tab={{item.tab}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see demo below

You should pass `item` to controller and make all logic inside controller

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.menu = [{
    tab: "One",
    nom: "Link A"
  }, {
    tab: "Two",
    nom: "Link B"
  }];

  $scope.selectItem = function(item) {

    $scope.tab = item.tab;


  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Tab: {{tab}}</h2>
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <span class="navbar-brand">Suivi Des Tables</span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{{item.class}}" ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active : item == itemcourant}"><a ng-click="selectItem(item)" href="#{{item.nom}}">{{item.nom}}</a>
            </li>
            <li><a ng-click="tab=1" href="#">test</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```